# Set HTML Page for printing in jsp request

Tags: jsp

I wanna store my html page for printing purpose. The code is

```
function printStore()
{
    var data=$("#print").html();
}
```

Can i store in `<%request.setAttribute("data",data) % > ;`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store.Because jsp will execute at server side and java script will execute at client side.

Answer (score 0):

@dimancrown What kind of scope you need for that data? If you want that data to be available throughout the application use jquery ajax to send it to servlet. Then you can get the data via servlet.

Comment: No, data contains the full html page. I want to pass this info to next jsp page.